# Is there a Python alternative to Matlab's cp2tform and imtransform?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

Code:

```
pt1=[input_points(:,2) input_points(:,1)];
pt2=[base_points(:,2) base_points(:,1)];
[pt1 pt2]=preProcessPoints(pt1,pt2);
transPr = cp2tform(pt1,pt2,'piecewise linear');
res = imtransform(I,transPr,'Xdata',[1 texturesize(1)],'YData',[1 texturesize(2)],'XYscale',1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes. You may check [scipy.ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html). If somehow not all functionality needed exists there, its still should be pretty straightforward to implement them your self.

**Update:**
Don't expect a one to one correspondence between the functionality. Study more on `map_coordinates` and `geometric_transform`, they should provide similar enough functionality.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Just glancing at cp2tform shows that it has more than a 1000 LOC, and those aren't 1000 lines of simple code either; it's advanced math.

Comment: @wgoty: updated my answer for a while ago. So the `Python alternative` seems to be reasonable straightforward enough. BTW, did my answer helped you? Thanks